# Разница работы QVector append и push_back

Tags: c++, qt5

```
//Этим можно не забивать голову, в своей сути - Vector<T>
//Указанно полностью, для "общей картины" вопроса    
typedef QVector<QPair<QPair<QString,LexemType>, QVector<int>>> tokenType ; 
    QSet<QString> MainWindow::_brackets={"(",")","{","}","[","]","<",">"};
    tokenType tokens;
    QStringList tmp = str.split(" ");
    for (int var = 0; var < tmp.length(); ++var)
    {
      if (_brackets.contains(tmp.at(var))) {processBrackets(tmp.at(var));}
    }
    
    QVector<tokenType> MainWindow::processBrackets(const QString &inputStr)
    {
    static QVector<tokenType> foundTokens;
    .......
    return  foundTokens;
    
    }
```

Почему   `tokens.push_back(d.at(var));` - выдает:

> mainwindow.cpp:54:24: error: no matching member function for call to
> 'push_back' qvector.h:272:17: note: candidate function not viable: no
> known conversion from 'const QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, LexemType>,
> QVector > >' to 'const QPair<QPair<QString, LexemType>,

> QVector >' for 1st argument qvector.h:273:10: note: candidate
> function not viable: no known conversion from 'const
> QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, LexemType>, QVector > >' to
> 'QPair<QPair<QString, LexemType>, QVector >' for 1st argument

,а
`tokens.append(d.at(var));` - нет?

Хотя
`tokens.push_back(d.at(var));` - внутри устроен как  `void push_back(T &&t) { append(std::move(t))};`

- ссылаясь на тот же  `inline void append(const QVector<T> &l) { *this += l; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push_back` может добавлять только один элемент, а `append` - копию вектора-аргумента.

Ругань компилятора

```
mainwindow.cpp:54:24: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back' qvector.h:272:17: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, LexemType>, QVector > >' to 'const QPair<QPair<QString, LexemType>,
```

как раз на то, что Вы пытаетесь засунуть в `push_back` целый вектор, а не его элемент.

Comment: Ок, понял, спасибо. Одно уточнение:но, ведь внутри push_back - вызов append? Разве такой "проброс" Не определяется компилятором?

Comment: @BadCatss, `T &&` про перемещение временного объекта. Ваш же код ссылается на объект, принадлежащий другому владельцу(`QSet`)

Comment: У append есть перегрузка для аргументов типа T и QVector<T>. У push_back такой перегрузки нет и принимает он только T. Здесь T - это шаблонный аргумент класса QVector, которому задан `QPair<...>`. Если бы push_back сам был определён как шаблонная функция, то такой проброс бы состоялся.